# Why do I see a CRON session opening and closing every hour in /var/log/auth.log?

Tags: server, cron

I am quite fresh with Linux as a whole, so this may be a silly question - but
I would still like to know the answer

This morning when I look at my /var/log/auth.log (which I've been told to make a habit)
I notice that once an hour  it has logged an event that looks like this:

```
     May 13 20:17:01 Ubuntu-Server-1401-VM CRON[2280]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
     May 13 20:17:01 Ubuntu-Server-1401-VM CRON[2280]: session closed for user root
```

It has then proceeded to happen every hour at x:17:01 until I opened the log.
An SSH connection to this server has been kept alive during this time (where the log entires occured). My best guess is that every hour my SSH client has looked to see whether or not it could obtain root access as a way to verify the connection to the SSH connection to the server - but I would like to be on the safe side. Does anyone know what this is?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Assuming you have not changed anything from the default `cron` setup, this is your `/etc/crontab` running. On my Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS server, its contents include:

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
```

So, `cron` wakes up every hour and runs any scrips located in `/etc/cron.hourly`. You probably don't have any which is why it doesn't do anything. It simply runs a `root` session which executes [`run-parts`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/run-parts.8.html) and then closes the session again.

Comment: got it disabled, must just a waste....

Comment: and can you disable this without issue ?

Answer (score 23):

These log entries were written by the PAM libraries when the `crond` daemon ran tasks in the background. `crond` runs jobs on a schedule, on behalf of the system and the users on the system.

Every user has their own `crontab` configuration file, which can be edited with the `crontab -e` command or shown using `crontab -l`. The system administrator can also configure jobs via a plethora of `/etc/` files and directories; `/etc/cron.d/` provides an easy place for services to drop their own configurations, and `/etc/crontab` drives the `hourly`, `daily`, and `weekly` directories, as well as runs whatever the administrator may choose to run.

`crond` will change users to the correct user (either specified in the `/etc/crontab` file and the `/etc/cron.d/` directory, or from the user-supplied `crontab` files) before running the jobs; it uses the [PAM system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module) to change users.

PAM provides a single place to configure different ways to authenticate and authorize users and provide session setup, as well as provide a way to change passwords (or other authentication tokens). Every service that uses PAM has a configuration file in `/etc/pam.d/` that describes which PAM modules to use when 'logging in' a user.

My `/etc/pam.d/cron` file looks like this:

```
# The PAM configuration file for the cron daemon

@include common-auth

# Read environment variables from pam_env's default files, /etc/environment
# and /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
session       required   pam_env.so

# In addition, read system locale information
session       required   pam_env.so envfile=/etc/default/locale

@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive 

# Sets up user limits, please define limits for cron tasks
# through /etc/security/limits.conf
session    required   pam_limits.so
```

This ensures limits that are configured for users are applied to users' tasks when they run them via `cron`. If you wanted to change those limits per-service, you could configure `pam_limits.so` in this file with your own `conf=/etc/security/cron-limits.conf` and apply different limits than ssh logins (`/etc/pam.d/sshd`) or console logins (`/etc/pam.d/login`).